# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x+\sqrt{x^3+1}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is what I've done:

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x+\sqrt{x^3+1}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x(1+\sqrt{x+1})}{x}= 2.$

I know this is incorrect since wolfram alpha gives $\infty $ and I assume that I for some reason can't do what I did in the first step but I can't figure out why.

Comment: $ x \sqrt{x+1} = \sqrt{x^3+x^2},$ not $\sqrt{x^3+1}.$

Comment: There is no hesitation, the numerator tends to $1$ ! When you pull out the factor $x$, you get $\sqrt{x+x^{-2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${x+\sqrt{x^3+1}\over x} = 1+ \sqrt{x^3+1 \over x^2} = 1+ \sqrt{x + {1\over x^2}} \geq {1 \over \sqrt{x^2} } = {1\over x} \longrightarrow +\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

As $x \to 0$, we have
$$
\sqrt{x^3+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\;x^3 + O(x^6)
\\
x + \sqrt{x^3+1} = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}\;x^3 + O(x^6)
\\
\frac{x + \sqrt{x^3+1}}{x} = \frac{1}{x} + 1 + \frac{1}{2}\;x^2 + O(x^5)
\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x + \sqrt{x^3+1}}{x} = \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+\sqrt{x^3+1}}{x} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0}x+ \lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{x^3+1}}{\lim_{x \to 0}x}, $$

and so the numerator converges to $1$ while the denominator to $0$.

Comment: This method doesn't work in general: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{h(x)} \neq \frac{\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)+ \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)}{\lim_{x \to 0}h(x)}. $$

Especially when you have $\frac{0}{0}$ type indeterminate limits.

So I would avoid this method.

Comment: @AdamRubinson thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $x>0.$

$0< \dfrac{1}{x}<1+\dfrac{1}{x}=$

$1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{0+1}}{x} <
\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^3+1}}{x}.$

Hence ?